# Why is this error happening: Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am running a GUI system in MATLAB and I am a beginner with working with GUI's.

The code is extensively long and so I am going to just put in what and where I have things and see if it is enough information for help to be given, thanks.

in my first GUi I have this in the opening function:

```
HW12_result_bhanford(handles.scan_age, handles.check_athlete, handles.radio_male, handles.radio_female)
```

this is supposed to be transferring these four variables over to my third GUI named
  HW12_result_bhanford

In my second GUI I have this written in the opening function:

```
age = varargin{1}
athlete = varargin{2}
male = varargin{3}
female = varargin{4}
```

I then use these four variables(age, athlete, male, female) later in the second GUI and I
  assume them to be the equivalent value of the corresponding variable passed from the first
  GUI.
  When I run everything the error that comes back is Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

if anyone could help me, that would be awesome. If you cannot help without the entire code I understand.

Comment: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions` means that you are at some point trying to access data that does not exist. The error message should tell you where this happens in the code, and then you can go check what's happening yourself. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/debugging-code.html

Comment: it says the problem is with   age = varargin{1}   so I am unsure whether the problem would be with varargin{1}, age, or with the variable corresponding to age from the previous GUI. I am guessing youre unable to know without the rest of the code.

Comment: When debugging, print out `varargin` to the command window to see what is actually being passed as an input to the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You use `varargin` if your argument list is variable, and varargin has to be in your function definition.

```
function HW12_result_bhanford(varargin)
```

In this case function receive a cell array as an input, so you can get individual arguments with `varargin{1}` etc.

If you put your arguments together as a structure, you can pass this structure as an argument along.

```
function HW12_result_bhanford(handles)
```

But if the function definition has individual arguments, for example,

```
function HW12_result_bhanford(age, athlete, male, female)
```

you cannot use `varargin`, just process the arguments as is.

Read more on how to use [VARARGIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html).